# How to download/gunzip a file and obtain an InputStream of the actual file?

Tags: java, file-io, gunzip

I have a url of a gzipped file. I would like to obtain an InputStream of the actual file in Java. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean, something like [GZIPInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html)?

```
InputStream is = ....
InputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(is);
```

Comment: yes, I guess i did. I was assuming I needed to perform operations on the GZIPInputStream object. Sometimes the simplest solution is the hardest to see.

Comment: @Dirk, Thanks for the link. I have a helper method that looks at the end of the filename and uses GZIPInputStream or GZIPOutputStream as appropriate.  You may want BufferedInputStream before the GZIP as well.